# Как найти документ по параметру _id mongodb node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

я пытаюсь найти документ в mongodb по параметру _id с помощью функции findOne через оф. драйвер mongodb на node js

код:

```
await users.findOne({_id: req.params.userId}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {console.log(err)}
        console.log("result: ", doc)
})
```

терминал:

```
result: null
```

*пробовал искать в гугле, ничего не нашел.*

Answer (score 1):

req.params.userId должен быть обернут в ObjectId

Mongoose

```
id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId)
```

Mongodb

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId
id = ObjectId(req.params.userId)
```