# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, веб-сервер, mongoose

ошибка в мангус... я новичок в этом и не понимаю в чем ошибка, при клике add to cart. Вроде все верно передаю в запросах. Прикладываю скрины.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Тутъ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1402835/366344)

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста в моем случае куда внести этот объект? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: У вас item.id = undefined, в запросе. И при поиске в монго по _id, нужно преобразовывать в ObjectId.